# Long loading time on a search form in an ACCESS FE/BE environment

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm turning to you for some help on an ACCESS FE/BE app.

I'm using VBA for quite some time now (Though only on ACCESS for like a year) but that's the first project where I actually need to setup a back-end on a distant server, and I'm struggling with what seems to be a connection issue (I'm no VBA Dev). I'm certainly doing things wrong, so feel free to redirect me on a good tutorial that could help me clear things up if that's the case.

So, my app is basically a storage database, we work on a file, add it to the BE through the FE with all relevant info, and users can look up things like client ID or name to get a list of all the files related and see where they are stored.

Everything works super well in local and is pretty much usable all-round with one user on a distant server, but things get complicated with multiple users. I have figured that the database seems to need to be entirely loaded in RAM to perform a search on its content, and that anytime someone modify a record, some flag tells Access to re-download the database on a new search to get everything fresh, which takes way too long (Around 30 seconds each time). Everything working as expected I guess, but I struggle to find a good way to have a multi-user app then. I can't imagine that's how it's supposed to work, so I guess I'm doing things the wrong way (Or it's the server, which is mainly a storage server for the entire company, that is not made for traffic purpose, but I dunno).

I have pinned the problem to this, which is a part of the code called when someone uses the search form :

```
Set searchRST = dbs.OpenRecordset(SQLQuery, dbOpenSnapshot)

        If searchRST.RecordCount <> 0 Then
            If searchRST.EOF = False Then
                searchRST.MoveNext
            End If
            searchRST.MoveFirst
        End If

        Select Case searchRST.RecordCount
            Case 0
                .Controls("search_Results").Visible = False
                .Controls("Button_Load").Visible = False

                MsgBox ("No record found.")

            Case 1
                fileRST.FindFirst ("[ID] = " & searchRST![ID])
                Forms(const_File).Bookmark = fileRST.Bookmark
                .Controls("search_Results").Visible = False
                .Controls("Button_Load").Visible = False
                Call launchFileMode(modeVal)

            Case Is > 1
                searchRST.MoveLast
                "Others checks are made before displaying results in a subform control
```

Basically, when you enter your search criteria and click on a button, it filters the database based on the SQLQuery string provided, goes through the entire filtered recordset so it can load it afterward, and either show a message " Nothing found " if the RecordCount of the filtered recorset is 0, show the only file available if it's 1 (By setting the bookmark of the recordset currently loaded by the File form to the bookmark of the filtered recordset), or show the filtered recordset in a subform if it's > 1 so the user can select the file to access.

The SQLQuery is a string programmatically created from the different searching criteria ( It was designed to handle a multiple criteria search but that's not used for now ), which gives something like this :

```
SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM [DB] WHERE [CLIENT ID] LIKE '0123456';"
```

The loading time is not at the same point depending on the RecordCount :

- If it's 0, the line `Set searchRST = dbs.OpenRecordset(SQLQuery, dbOpenSnapshot)` will get the charge ;
- If it's 1, the line `searchRST.MoveNext` will get the charge ;
- If it's > 1, the line `searchRST.MoveLast` ( Which is used to load the subform with all records of the filtered recordset so you can scroll down in it without delay ) will get the charge.

That's were I'm lost. Why isn't it the same line that get the loading time regardless of how big the recordset is ? If it's actually the action of retrieving the data that is problematic, it should be the dbs.OpenRecordset line that cause the problem in every situation, no ?

I'm probably doing things the worst way ever, so any advice on this or on any other way of handling these search would be greatly appreciated!

Feel free to ask for any detail that could be helpful.

(And sorry if it's not crystal clear, I'm working against the clock to post this from work where I can access the accdb file)

Comment: I use RecordsetClone and Bookmark for a search operation - no recordset object variable. Ex: `Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "LabNum='" & Me.OpenArgs & "'"   
Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark`

Comment: Thanks! I will try that tomorrow. (Though I think I already tried to set a RecordsetClone months ago (I'm returning to this issue just now), and it didn't work with the search, but maybe I was using it differently. Will try that.)

Comment: Happens I won't be able to work on it for at least two weeks, so thanks a lot for the clues to June7 and Albert D.Kallal, I will try your approaches as soon as I can and see if there is any improvement, but for now I'm marking Albert answer as accepted as it is most probably a server's type related problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is only one record, then why a find first? If the query is similar to what you posted, then in most cases such a search for a ID will likely only return one record and should be fast. So most important is that the criteria limits the number of records pulled. Assuming some type of "key" is used, then as noted in the vast majority of cases you only likely will grab/return/pull one record from the server. You also need to 100% ensure that you have a persistent connection (a bound form remains open to a linked table that points to the back end.

It is also assumed that your application is split, and that each workstation has a copy of the FE.

It also assumed that the shared folder on the server for the back end is on your local network, and not some remote "VPN" type of connection over the internet which is usually about 100 times slower then your typical office network. You can read about the speed difference between a LAN (local area network) vs that of a WAN (wide area network) here:

http://www.kallal.ca//Wan/Wans.html

If you are working from a LAN, then I don't see why performance is slow, or any kind of issue (if it application runs fast with one user, but slow with two, then 9 out of 10 times, the persistent connection trick will fix this issue).

So basic assumptions are:
You application is split.
Each workstation gets a copy of the front end.
You have a persistent connection.
You are working on a standard office LAN as opposed to some kind of WAN (or VPN).

Comment: I guess it's a WAN? Definitely not a LAN, as the server is accessible by at least all the central sites (Which are half a country wide). I will do some speed tests to see if the server is the problem.

Will check if I have a persistent connection open too this afternoon.

Comment: Well, if the WAN uses the internet, then you going to be many times slower. Read that article of mine. A typical high speed internet has say, 15mbps, your office LAN is usually a 1000. You can do the grade 3 math here. So yes, do inquire about connection speed, but your typical T1 line high speed internet is 10, or 50 times slower. (so 3 seconds becomes say 150 seconds (2.5 minutes). So say if 4 minutes is too slow, then spending even more big bucks to double the speed means your 2-3 second query or operation now drops from 4 minutes down to 2 minutes. Consider SQL server for back end.

Comment: Yeah I read that article today (Pretty good by the way).Unfortunately I can't set an SQL server at work, and I can't set it anywhere else (Banks are not the kind of company to let info get out easily, and IT just won't allow us nor waste time to set anything for only one unit) and I think they removed the office local server last year. I will see with our local IT if I can set an unused local computer as a server, but your article is pretty much saying to avoid like plague setting the FE and BE on the same electric source.Will try your comments to see if there is any little improvement in WAN.